# React Load Binary File / URL scheme "file" is not supported

Tags: reactjs, file, binary

## Background

I built an app, which converts files from type A to type B (a binary file). I want to import and use a dummy file of type B to fill the data of file type A. The dummy always stays the same. The app has no backend. I want to share the html, so anything which requires turning off browser security etc., isn't an option.

## Problem

At the moment, I load the files as I found here, but this works only with a backend server:
[Requesting blob images and transforming to base64 with fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698967/requesting-blob-images-and-transforming-to-base64-with-fetch-api)

```
import dummy  from '../templates/Grid2.shp';

    let hex = await fetch(dummy)
        .then( response => response.blob() )
        .then( blob => new Promise( callback =>{
            let reader = new FileReader() ;
            reader.onload = function(){
                const serumShp = atob(this.result.substring(37)); // 37 strips the base64 info data:...
                callback(binaryToHex(serumShp))
            } ;
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob) ;
        }) ) ;
```

It works in my development but not at the built stage. As the browsers requests from the filesystem.

I found a solution over a file loader, but this solution also throws an error:
[Using file-loader to load binary file in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719048/using-file-loader-to-load-binary-file-in-react)

> import/no-webpack-loader-syntax

Also, I don't see any configuration files for Webpack. As far as I have seen I would need to `eject` them, which is also not recommended.

## Question:

How can I import binary files into my app without a backend server/any changes, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cannot help, but pointing out that there is a [general discussion](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3722) in CRA to support a more elegant way of importing binary/raw data. Sadly there doesn't seem to be much progress, the proposal is from 2018.